# How to set the Turbo C path in windows?

Tags: c, windows, path, turbo-c, tcc

How to set the turbo c path in windows globally so that i can compile and run my C programs (which are in other drives) using command prompt in windows XP?
Can any one tell me how to get commands at every drive in the command prompt just by typing in

```
c:\tcc
```

in command prompt in windows and turbo c environment?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- Go to the Start Menu, then Control Panel.
- Choose the "System" applet.
- Click on the "Advanced" tab.
- Click on "Environment Variables"
- Find the "Path" variable, and press "Edit"
- Append a semicolon, then the path to Turbo C

For setting the include and library paths, go to the same place, but instead of editing the "Path" variable, create a new variable called "INCLUDE", and set it to the location of your turboc "\include" directory; and create one called "LIB" and one called "CLASSPATH", and set them to your turboc "\lib" directory.

Comment: But then after doing that also it is saying that the conio.h and stdio.h can not be included.<p>shall we also give any paths for the include, library folders?

Answer (score 2):

Is there some reason why you're using such an old compiler? Turbo C was last released in the early 1990s, if I remember correctly.

I might suggest downloading the free [Visual Studio Express Edition](http://www.microsoft.com/Express/) which is a much more modern compiler and you will find many more people here who are willing to help. It also comes with good documentation and it's easier to search the net for articles and help for it.